# Absolute positioning not working Safari Mobile

Tags: css, mobile-safari

The search section in my site www.anahatainternational.org displays correctly across FF, Chrome, and Safari. But in Safari mobile it displays in the middle of the page.

```
#search_section {
position: absolute;
right: 490px;
top: 10px;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't safari mobile limited to a mobile device which is smaller then 490px? Is the page scrolling? Does it have to do with the size of the layout?

Comment: We need a bit more... Do the parent have the position:relative?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making few changes to the layout of the page so that you could make the #search_section relative to the header.

I have create a skeletal structure for it. http://jsfiddle.net/AACuy/

Also remove the left, top and position:absolute properties.

There are too many classes in the site for me to make changes using firebug and show the result.